# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/.../normal_logs/log_2023_05_04.log: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to save logs in a log file. For that I am creating a folder named 'normal_logs' and I want to create a log file with the extension '.log' with the current date. The folder named 'normal_logs' is successfully created, but log files are not created inside it. This is the code I am using.

```
public class LoggingModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private LogFileWriter mLogFileWriter;

    public static final String DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR = "/";
    public static final String LOG_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR + "estate_logs";
    public static final String TRANSACTION_LOG_DIR = LOG_DIR + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR + "transaction";

    public LoggingModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        File logsDir = new File(TRANSACTION_LOG_DIR+"/normal_logs");
        if (!logsDir.exists() && !logsDir.mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create dir");
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
        String path = TRANSACTION_LOG_DIR +  "/normal_logs/"  + "log_" + formatter.format(new Date()) + ".log";

        File logFile = new File(path);
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            // Create the log file (if not exists)
            try {
                boolean fileCreated = logFile.createNewFile();
                if(!fileCreated){
                    throw new IOException("gjhsghsg");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mLogFileWriter = new LogFileWriter(logFile);

    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void log(String message) {
        mLogFileWriter.write(message);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "LoggingModule";
    }
}
```

I have searched on Google and most of the answers include adding permissions to AndroidManifest.xml. But I have added permissions already.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Please help me to find out why the log file is not created inside the directory.

Comment: /file_path/ does not match 'normal_logs'. And it is an impossible path too

Comment: I have added 'file_path' name since I could not upload the question since the title is too long. The actual file path is /storage/emulated/0/estate_logs/transaction/normal_logs/log_2023_05_04.log

Comment: We cannot see that that would be the used path as all that we see is  Constants.TRANSACTION_LOG_DIR and nobody knows what that would be. Dont use constants if you ask for help. Post code that is understandable. That we can follow.

Comment: These are the constant I have used.                                                                            public static final String DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR = "/";
    public static final String LOG_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR + "estate_logs";
    public static final String TRANSACTION_LOG_DIR = LOG_DIR + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR + "transaction";

Comment: My god... Put that in your post. On the first lines of your code. Or there were used. We want to be able to follow your code. Make it easy for us. And... Better not use constants at all if you come for help was the message.

Comment: `File logFile = new File(path);` You declared 'path' from constants. You should not have declared 'path' at all but instead use 'logsDir' like File logFile = new File(logsDir, fileName);

Comment: Sorry. Now I think it is clear.

Comment: I hate your messing around with constants ;-) Unreadable code. Please tell Android version of used device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because Android version 11 does not support creating files inside the 'emulate' directory. Therefore we need to use external storage for saving files. This code segment resolved my problem.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
```